# Errors regarding sources.list and how to fix key ring on Debian 8

Tags: linux, debian

[image]

I have a Debian machine and trying to download gdebi core but can't due to unable to download some python libraries. I am still new to keys, so I am wondering how I fix this issue, as I need to see the specific keys missing, how to grab that key from a keyserver,
How to import that key into gpg or apt-key.

Comment: The keys have expired, there’s no way for you to fix that. You need to disable key verification, see the linked answers for details.